# R - How to extract single dataframes from list of lists?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, split, dataset

I have a list of lists called `step2` containing dataframes  like this one:

[image: List of lists]

And I want to extract every element in the list as a single dataframe, so that I have one dataframe called `Likert_rank_Americas`, `Likert_rank_APAC`, `Likert_rank_Civil_law` and so on for each dataframe contained in the list.

I tried with this:

`list2env(step2,envir=.GlobalEnv)`

But I only get the sub-lists contained in the main one as single objects, like so:

[image]

While what I want instead are the underlying dataframes as standalone objects, with the names as specified above. Is it possible to do this in a neat way without using `list2env` for each sub-list and then manually renaming each dataset?

I am quite new to R so apologies if the solution's easy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Without any data provided by you, what you want specifically is hard to guess, but at a minimum, to access a list of dataframes you need to follow this kind of logic...

```
 a.1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:9, nrow=3))
 a.2 <- data.frame(matrix(6:14, nrow=3))
 data <- list(list(a.1,a.2),list("1","2"))
 # NOTE: want only info from data[1] processed

 library(purrr)

 b <- map_dfr(data[1],rbind)

 b
 class(b)
 dim(b)


 # > b
 # X1 X2 X3
 # 1  1  4  7
 # 2  2  5  8
 # 3  3  6  9
 # 4  6  9 12
 # 5  7 10 13
 # 6  8 11 14
 # > class(b)
 # [1] "data.frame"
 # > dim(b)
 # [1] 6 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this oneliner should work.
The function 'list2env' assigns all list components to the global environment.
The function 'lapply' applies the function 'list2env' to every element of the list 'step2'.

```
step2%>% lapply(.%>% {list2env(., envir=.GlobalEnv)})
```

You can rename the dataframes before doing so of course.

```
names(step2$Geography)<- c(
'Likert_Rank_Americas', 
'Likert_Rank_APAC', 
'Likert_Rank_EMEA', 
'Likert_Rank_Global')

names(step2$Legal_System)<- c(
'Likert_Rank_Civil_law',
'Likert_Rank_Common_law')
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a quick reproducible dataset for testing with (this is good practice to include when asking for help)

```
dat <- list(list(data.frame(), data.frame(), data.frame()), list(data.frame(), data.frame(), data.frame()))
names(dat) <- c('list1' , 'list2')
names(dat$list1) <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
names(dat$list2) <- c('D', 'E', 'F')
```

Then I used

`lapply(dat, list2env, .GlobalEnv)`

Edit: To rename the dataframes, use the same structure as above where I named the sample dataframe, but use the names you want the end objects to have. If you want to automate this process, I would seperate it into a different question, but I suspect you would be able to find another post with the answer already.

Something like (pseudo-code)...

```
name_vec <- paste0('naming_convention_', names(step2$Geography))
names(step2$Geography) <- name_vec
```